# Event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tiddlywiki

I have these bits of code that are supposed to bug two functions and fire events for them. For some reason, however, the event does not seem to trigger. They log to the console as expected, but the event never gets fired.

```
//Show backstage event
(function( $, oldRem ){
    backstage.show = function(){
        console.log("yup, I'm the right one");
        var resp = oldRem.apply( this, arguments );
        $("#backstageArea").trigger("showBackstage");
        return(resp);
    };
})( jQuery, backstage.show );
//Hide backstage event
(function( $, oldRem ){
    backstage.hide = function(){
        console.log("And so am I.");
        var resp = oldRem.apply( this, arguments );
        if(anim && config.chkAnimate) {setTimeout( 'jQuery("#backstageArea").trigger("hideBackstage")', config.animDuration);}
        else {$("#backstageArea").trigger("hideBackstage");}
        return(resp);
    };
})( jQuery, backstage.hide );

//Resize never logs its console message.
jQuery.bind("hideBackstage", function(){topbar.resize();});
jQuery.bind("showBackstage", function(){topbar.resize();});
```

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery("#backstageArea").bind(...` instead of `jQuery.bind(...`?

Comment: That did it. Can you put it in an answer?

Comment: If you haven't already you might check out [**Firebug**](https://getfirebug.com/), excellent tool for debugging javascript and other errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify what element(s) to `bind` to, so try:

```
jQuery("#backstageArea").bind(...
```

instead of

```
jQuery.bind(...
```

(And if you're using jQuery version 1.7+ you may like to switch to the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - will have the same effect for this purpose, but is the recommended way of doing things from v1.7 on.)